# Set photo dates based on EXIF data when adding additional images to an existing album

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

The new Facebook photo upload tool can read timestamps from the EXIF data when creating a new album. That is awesome, especially for large albums.

However, when adding more photos to an existing album, the feature is still available, but doesn't seem to work. The uploaded photos will remain dated the same as the album date.

Is there another way of automatically date-tagging bulks of Facebook photos when adding to an existing album?